# Chart text responses in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google form that has the following multiple choice question:

```
How would you rate your general well-being today?
-Very well
 -Slightly less than par
 -Poor
 -Very poor
 -Terrible
```

The form then saves to a google sheet. A column of this data might look like this:

```
 How would you rate your general well-being today?
Slightly less than par
Very well
Very well
Very well
Very well
Slightly less than par
Very well
```

Where the question is in the top row...and each subsequent row is the a day of the week (and how the person was feeling that day).

I am wanting to view this data in a chart (pie or bar); but am not sure how to handle it since its text and not numbers. One way I was considering is the add some sort of function to the cell that would convert the response to an integer so it could be charted. So in the case of this question the scale would be 1-5; 1 being `Very Well` and 5 being `Terrible`. Feels kind of janky, but wanted to check and see if there is an easier way. The once I had a text respesnetation of the responses I could easilty put a chart on them.

Comment: Yeap, that's how I have personally done it in the past. Just have one nested if formula which applies weighting. Could possibly have another sheet which serves as an index making the nested if formula easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing.

In a separate column I have the following function:

`=SWITCH(K2,"Very well",0,"Slightly less than par",1,"Poor",2,"Very poor",3,"Terrible",4)`

Where column K2 contains the users response. I copied this function to all rows in this column, so now I have numbers 1-5 to represent the users response. Now just highlight the column and add the date on the X-axis and it gives me a nice chart like this:

[image]

Might be nice to have the labels rather than numbers on the left side if anyone has suggestions on that.